# Entity framework query to include child entities of entity collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a `ticket` entity that has `ticketNotes` (0 to many) and would like to pull back the user details for who created each note when I query tickets.

I use the following code to query a ticket

```
var ticket = (from t in context.Tickets
.Include(t=>t.Site)
.Include(t=>t.Caller)
.Include(t=>t.Caller.Site)
.Include(t => t.Notes)
.Include(t=>t.OpenedByUser)
select t).First(t => t.TicketId == ticketId);
```

My `TicketNote` Class is:

```
public class TicketNote
{
    public Guid TicketNoteId { get; set; }
    public string NoteText { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }
    public Guid TicketId { get; set; }
    public virtual Ticket Ticket { get; set; }
    public bool ReadOnly { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateTimeDeleted { get; set; }
    public Guid TenantId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DefaultValue(typeof(Guid), "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")]
    public Guid CreatedByUserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CreatedByUserId")]
    public virtual User CreatedByUser { get; set; }
 }
```

I would like to add

`.Include(t => t.Notes.CreatedByUser)`

However as notes is a collection I don't get the option.

Please advise the best approach to achieve pulling back the CreatedByUser which is NULL at the moment.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if `Any()` would work here - `.Include(t => t.Notes.Any().CreatedByUser)`?

Comment: Hi, Thanks I just tried this but I don't have any entity options after any so it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe this article will help you: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/788559/Loading-Related-Entities-with-Entity-Framework-A-B). Especially parts concerning explicit loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include more complex statements to get at multilevel collections.  Try the following:

```
.Include(t => t.Notes.Select(n => n.CreatedByUser))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `ticket` variable which have property `Notes` inside it.
For performance you may use

```
ticket.Notes.Select(t => n.CreatedByUser)
```

Comment: Please can you advise how to use this when returning the ticket? I return a ticket entity in my repository so can't call a select later as the context is closed.